# Passing data from template to view in Django

Tags: django

From a Django template, I pass an id as a parameter along with its url.

```
<a href="/add/?q={{mytable.id}}" >Next</a>
```

When I click next, it goes to the page 'add' with id parameter (localhost/add/?q=5c23451). I assign the value of this parameter to a variable.

```
q1=request.GET.get('q','')
```

Then, I try to get all the objects from the database where id='id' as follows:

```
obj=mytable.objects.get(id='q1')
```

The problem is when I try to print q1 it is always empty. Could you please tell me where am going wrong?

Entire View

```
def addview(request):
    q1=request.GET.get('q','')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form= myform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj=mytable.objects.get(id=q1)
            obj.info = form.cleaned_data['info']
            obj.url= form.cleaned_data['content']
            obj.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/')

    else:
        form=myform()
    variables=RequestContext(request, {
    'form':form
    })

    return render_to_response('/add/add.html', variables,)
```

forms.py

```
class myform(forms.Form):

info=forms.CharField(max_length=100)
content=forms.URLField()
```

Comment: You might be better off using the django url structure with CBVs, i.e. `{%url 'myapp:my_detail_view' pk=obj.pk %}`

Comment: try <a href="/add/{{mytable.id}}/" >Next</a>

Comment: can you post your view ? there is no error in your way..also "I try to get all the objects from the database where id='id' " is incorrect because, `get` must contain unique document.otherwise use `filter`

Comment: Where are you trying to print `q1` . Also, what is `q1` in y our view ?

Comment: @itzmeontv I have edited the post. Now it contains my view.

Comment: @AjayGupta No luck :-/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're querying the string `"q1"` rather than the variable `q1`.

```
obj = mytable.objects.get(id=q1)
```

Note that lines in Python shouldn't end with semicolons.

**Edit**

This is happening when you POST the form, not on the initial GET. That's because GET variables aren't preserved when you submit the form.

You really need to go back to basics on this. Passing IDs via GET parameters is not the right way to do things in Django. You should pass it in the URL itself; that is more easily produced by the built-in tools, and the value will be preserved when you submit.

Firstly, your `addview` URL needs to accept the parameter:

```
url(r'^add/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.addview, name='add'),
```

and your link should now use the `{% url %}` template tag:

```
<a href="{% url "add" id=mytable.id %}" >Next</a>
```

Now, your view needs to accept that parameter:

```
def addview(request, id):
    obj = mytable.objects.get(id=id)
```

This will fix your problem by itself, but there is another improvement you should make, which is to use a ModelForm rather than a plain form. Change the form as follows:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('info', 'url')
```

and now your view becomes:

```
def addview(request, id):
    obj = mytable.objects.get(id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(request.POST, instance=obj)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('success')
    else:
        form = MyForm(instance=obj)
    return render(request, 'add/add.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Thanks, but it did not work. I have edited my question to contain the entire view. Could you please look into it?

Comment: But now you seem to be using `uid` rather than `id`. Which is it? And note that lines in Python don't end with commas, either.

Comment: Sorry that's id (edited the post again). It goes to /add but the error is 'mytable matching query does not exist.' The error is shown in this line: 'obj=mytable.objects.get(id=q1)'. I think q1 doesn't get the value of q.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That solved most of the issues. Now it throws a noreversematch error. '  

Reverse for 'add' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'id': u'5caed0'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['add/(?P<q>\\d+)/$']

Comment: I don't know why you changed it to `<q>`, it should be `<id>`. But I didn't realise you were using non-numeric IDs. So the pattern should be `r'^add/(?P<id>\w+)/$'`

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are trying is incorrect. `a href` is using for `GET` request. If you click that link, it will not post any data.Also it will not enter into `if request.method == 'POST'` condition.Then if you have a form to `POST`.Then set form attribute `action='/add/?q={{mytable.id}}'`.Then it will have `request.POST` and `request.GET` (now).